# Pointer within a custom structure

Tags: go

Recently, I got exposed to following source code from *"Go Programming Blueprints"* book.

```
type googleGeometry stuct {
    *googleLocation `json:"location"`
}
type googleLocation struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat"`
    Lng float64 `json:"lng"`
}
```

What I don't understand is why **googleGeometry** structure uses pointer instead of literal, and what is the reason behind such declaration?

I would expect below declaration instead of a pointer.

```
type googleGeometry stuct {
    gl googleLocation `json:"location"`
}
```

Comment: That is an *embedded* type, not a struct member. There is a distinction there, but I'm still not clear why they chose a pointer rather than a plain struct in this case.

Comment: @captncraig it's still a struct member; an [embedded type is a kind of struct member](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it is because `location` can be `null` or would be absent at all.
Such cases can be represented with pointers. Because if it would be literal you will always have default values for `lat` and `lng`.
Please take a look on this example: [Why pointer?](https://play.golang.org/p/rpTGWphQry)

And this with a value type instead of reference: [Value types always have default values](https://play.golang.org/p/g23KpuYIqH)

Comment: Yeah, it seems strange on a struct that doesn't contain anything else, but I did a struct with *several* embedded pointers recently to control which groups of fields did and didn't appear in JSON output. Perhaps they're doing that elsewhere in this library, and this one is just for consistency? Or perhaps they really just do want to serialize `{}` sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`googleGeometry` **embeds** a pointer to a `googleLocation`. It is essentially an unnamed field so that the `Lat` and `Lng` fields are accessible as if they were top level fields.

Why use

```
type googleGeometry stuct {
    *googleLocation `json:"location"`
}
```

instead of

```
type googleGeometry stuct {
    googleLocation `json:"location"`
}
```

?

I think they made the wrong call here. The pointer is nillable so if you do:

```
g := googleGeometry{}
fmt.Println(g.Lat)
```

you will get a nil reference panic. If you embed a non-pointer struct, the fields will be automatically initialized to zeros.

Comment: On top of that, nil pointers will not be marshalled to JSON. Otherwise you could end up with `"location": ""`

Comment: Haven't read the book, but it could be that `*googleLocation` implents some interface that they want `googleGeometry` to implement as well by using composition, embedding `googleLocation` would not work, just my 2c.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the entire context of the question, however when a pointer is embedded inside the struct, even when the variable of type `googleGeometry` is passed by value the embedded `googleLocation` pointer still points to the same memory address as the initial variable (as the address is simply copied). Therefore although the original struct is passed by value both original and the copied variables share the same embedded pointer. That might be the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is JSON (de)serialization. If you want to unmarshal JSON into a struct and validate if certain attributes are present in the document using a pointer is a convenient way. Since the unmarshaller will leave missing fields `nil`.

The following code code will print: `missing location attribute`

```
func main() {
    doc := []byte("{}") // json that misses a location member

    var geometry googleGeometry
    json.Unmarshal(doc, &geometry)

    if geometry.googleLocation == nil {
        fmt.Println("missing location attribute")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("location attribute unmarshalled correctly")
    }
}
```

See: https://play.golang.org/p/hTj5HvI-AE